# Accented characters not correctly imported with BULK INSERT

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, character-encoding, bulkinsert

I am importing a source CSV file, I don't know the source encoding and I can only see either `ï¿½` (ANSI encoding) or `�` (UTF8-without-BOM encoding) when I open a the file with `Notepad++` ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953430/how-to-get-encoding-of-cvs-file)).

This file has been imported to the database `mssql-2008` using `bulk insert`:

```
DECLARE @bulkinsert NVARCHAR(2000)              
  SET @bulkinsert =               
 N'BULK INSERT #TempData FROM ''' +               
@FilePath +               
N''' WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,FIELDTERMINATOR = ''","'',ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'')'              
     EXEC sp_executesql @bulkinsert
```

This is then copied to the regular `table1` from `#tempData` in a column1 (`varchar()`). Now when I look into this `table1` I see some `?` in place of those characters.

I have tried to `cast` to `nvarchar()` but it does not help.

when I digged into what those characters really are with support of the link we download at same time, I saw that the characters were `é`,`ä`,`å` and so on.

I would use `replace` to fix the data but I need to make some ugly codes and look into individual pattern of words and replace, so seems difficult.

database/table  collation: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`
column1(Varchar(80))

Can I change these characters to English-like characters or the original characters instead of `?` marks.

I have looked at [Collation and Unicode Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx#Complex_script) which did not help me. I understood what it means about encoding but did not supply me with [what to do](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). I have looked into most of the posts here in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) yes there are some posts about it but did not match my search.

I am unable to figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. Are you saying that when you import a text file, the data in SQL Server is incorrect? If so, you need to provide the following information: encoding of the text file, data type of the target column, where you are seeing the incorrect characters.

Comment: @Pondlife      Thanks for response. I have now updated the question I hope it is more clear.

Comment: I still don't understand all the details, but my best guess is that you're importing Unicode data into a `varchar` column instead of an `nvarchar` one. I suggest you make sure that all character columns in `#tempData` are `nvarchar` and then try adding `DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar'` to your [`BULK INSERT` command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365(v=sql.100).aspx). And forget about `table1` completely until you have clean data in `#tempData`.

Comment: @Pondlife Yes, the #tempData was created using varchar() for all the columns. Which I suppose this must be the problem, right?

Comment: Possibly, although since you aren't sure about the format of the source CSV file it may not fix it anyway. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934017/unprintable-characters-in-bcp-exe-output), where the file actually turned out to be binary, not text. Clarifying exactly what the format/content of the source file is would be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was answered in the comment.  Did you try it?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189941.aspx

Option DATAFILETYPE ='widenative'

Based on comment from Esailiga did the text get truncated before or after the bulk import.  I agree it sounds like the CSV file itself is single byte.   Unicode requires option DATAFILETYPE ='widenative'.  If the CSV file is single byte the is not magic translation back.

What is too bad is é is extended ASCII and supported with SQL char so more evidence the problem is at the CSV.
SELECT CAST('é' AS char(1))
notice this works as extended ASCII (<255)

Sounds like you need to go back to the source.

The ? in SQL is unknown.  Same as � in notepad.

Comment: It doesn't matter, even if he does everything correctly, he will end up with `�` because that's what the data is. You cannot fix a literal `�` in any way. This is not the case where `�` is just a superficial indication of error, it is the case where `�` *is* the literal data.

Comment: @Esailija OK I think I agree.  Still contend OP should have tested with DATAFILETYPE ='widenative' as would need that once the data is fixed.  Hopefully you will get the check on the other question.

Comment: @Blam          I will test and see if it works with 'widenative' as `datafiletype` type hope as well as change the #tempData defination to see if I can really get it right, else I will have to totally agree on Esailija's points. kudos for all the help.  I wish could give one more.

Comment: I agree with Esailija.  You need to fix both.  Get unicode and load unicode.  I hope you accept his other answer.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I can fix the encoding problem with the CODEPAGE option:

```
BULK
INSERT #CSV
FROM 'D:\XY\xy.csv'
WITH
(
   CODEPAGE = 'ACP',
   DATAFILETYPE ='char',
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
   FIRSTROW = 2
)
```

Possible values:
CODEPAGE = { 'ACP' | 'OEM' | 'RAW' | 'code_page' } ]

You can find more information about the option here:
[BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

Comment: Yep, bulk insert uses, by default, OEM codepage (likely codepage #437).

Answer (score 1):

I still cannot believe that after all these years Microsoft has not fixed this obvious bug. There should be no problem with èéêë etc because they are all ascii(<255). This quest is posed over and over again on many sites and the question has yet to be answered

My data is in a table in excel. having generated the insert into statements the table is parsed a 2nd time looking for asccii > 'z' and generating and update table set column statement to overwrite the imported data. Cumbersome but workable

Answer (score 1):

I've done it! After all these years and we were all looking in the wrong place. No work needed no rewriting scripts...

The problem lies with SSMS... if you "New Query" by right-clicking on "Queries" you get to rename the file but not create it that is done for you...

But... if you "Ctrl+N" you get a new query window to edit but no file is created... So you save it yourself and choose encoding on the save button... towards the bottom of the list you'll find UTF-8(without signature) codepage 65001

And that is it...

script after script open a new query window with "ctrl+N" copy and paste from  an existing query and save as directed above. And as if by magic it works

If like me you have tables in Excel... parse the table writing the output to the 1st column of a new workbook with 1 sheet in it and then saveas and choose utf-8 encoding

Speed things up with a template file containing a comment "-- utf-8" something like that. save it as utf-8 and use a file listing of *.sql pasted into excel to concatenate a list of 
=concatenate("ren templatefile.txt ", char(34), a1, char(34))
in b1 and drop it down

After all these years of manual solutions I am literally sweating with excitement at the discovery. Thank you for getting me so upset