# how to get encoding of csv file?

Tags: .net, csv, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accented characters not correctly imported with BULK INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949875/accented-characters-not-correctly-imported-with-bulk-insert)

A .net program running in my system provides me with a csv file. I would like to know the encoding of that file.

The csv file has `é`,`ä`,`å`,`æ` characters but is shown as �(UTF8-with BOM). Is there any possibility that I can bet back these characters to its original or its English like characters.

The csv file is created by a .net program running in the same machine under same user but after the creation of the file I cannot see the original characters.

[Related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949875/is-it-possible-to-change-the-characters-not-rightly-encoded-maks-all-of-them)

```
sample data (UTF8-Without BOM) from csv file. 

Pok�mon Black Version
TGC � Nintendo
on H�tel de R�ve  
La Reine Masqu�e et la Tour des Miroirs
```

Comment: How and with what you open that file? If you want to convert them to "safe" character you can find many posts here about that but you should be able to read them without any trick

Comment: @Adriano I have opened it with `Notepad++` I cannot see the original characters but these marks as mentioned. Changing the encoding to ASCII, ANSI just changes to some other garbage not real characters.

Comment: Open your file in hex editor and see what data is actually saved instead of your characters.

Comment: @NickolayO.    I have now opened the file in HxD hex editor, é seems to have hex value of `EF BF BD` and ANSI encoding gives me `ï¿½` character, willing to know what does it mean, and what shall I approach to get right character?

Comment: Did you check if you have the right BOM for UTF-8?

Comment: ï¿½ is correct for EF BF BD but é is E9.  Without BOM if it is not � is it correct?  How are you opening the file?   Have you tried other encoding?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143457.aspx

Comment: `22 43 61 74 65 67 6F 72 79 22 2C 22 53 75 62 63` first line of the file in hex editor, seems I do not have BOM, right? " is represented by 22 means no BOM in the beginning of the file.

Comment: Yes, it seems you don't have BOM. Try another encoding...

Comment: @Adriano  Opening the file in any of the encoding available in HxD hex editor as well as the Notepad++ seems not to show me the correct character. Do not know what must have gone wrong, Blam> I am not in a position to access the .net program and change inside.

Comment: @tough Try ANSI or ASCII encoding with the correct codepage...

Comment: You imported to SQL?  Did you use char or nchar?  Need nchar (or nvarchar) for unicode.

Comment: @Blam I have used `nvarchar()` to import to `#temptable` and later taken to varchar() column from `#temptable`. Is this causing me the problem, the last `varchar()` column?

Comment: Exactly.  Hope you still have your nvarchar data.  I have seen exactly this when loading unicode text to char.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you see `�`, when you decode the file as UTF-8, but you see `ï¿½`, when you decode it as Windows-1252, then the file *literally* contains `�`. I.E. It literally contains the bytes `0xEF 0xBF 0xBD` (UTF-8 for `�`) . Therefore the data is unrecoverable at this point.

This happens when physical encoding of some byte stream does not match the encoding used to decode it. So for instance, the physical encoding is Windows-1252, then a program decodes it to internal string using UTF-8 with replacement fallback. Now, the string internally contains `�`, but it is not inspected and is written to a file as UTF-8, and the resulting file is what you have.

---

To avoid the original screw up, it is a good idea to use exception fallback instead of replacement fallback when decoding files, for example:

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(
    "UTF-8",
    new EncoderExceptionFallback(),
    new DecoderExceptionFallback()
);

try
{
    File.ReadAllText(@"myfile.csv", enc);
}
catch (DecoderFallbackException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This file was not encoded in UTF-8, try some other encoding");
}
```

Now you get an exception when the file isn't UTF-8 and you can either try other encoding or let the user know that his file must be in UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for response, I am opening the file in `Windows server 2003` and has been imported to `mssql`as well, where it represents these as `?`. Wanted to know if there is some way I can recover to original or English like character seems better not to try this way, right?

Comment: @tough there is no way to recover except manual best guess I.E `Pok�emon` was probably originally `Pokémon`. I can edit in how this can happen.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Esailija.  Appears this data was single byte before it got to SQL.

In case the SQL was the problem will post as answer.

In SQL:

char and nchar are both single byte (ansii).

nchar and nvarchar are double byte (unicode).

If you load unicode into char it get packed into single byte.
I have loaded unicode into char and any uncode > 255 was translated to �.

[Using Unicode Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223981%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

How to test

SELECT CAST('a' AS char(1))

SELECT CAST('é' AS char(1))
notice this works as extended ASCII (<255)

SELECT CAST(N'Ƶ' AS char(1))

SELECT CAST(N'Ƶ' AS nchar(1))

SELECT CAST(N'Ƹ' AS char(1))

SELECT CAST(N'Ƹ' AS nchar(1))

notice Ƶ and Ƹ both cast to same ? (for don't know)

Comment: I have now added a related question, which has more details on the `mssql` side. Thanks for more info on encoding in SQL and was informative.